# How to pack all the project files and make installer for python project

Tags: python, windows-installer

I have a python project which has below directory structure:

```
logs
    -> app.log
output
    -> out.json
src
    -> encrypt_data.py
    -> decrypt_data.py
app.py
```

I have above directories `logs`, `output`, `src` which further contains files in them. `app.py` is the main python script which is dependent on above directory and files. I am using `python 3.6` and `app.py` needs some python libraries in order for it to run.

I am looking for an installer which can create a `setup.exe` file which when run, perform below actions:

1. Install python3.6 on user's system (if python is not already there)
2. Install required python libraries
3. Ask user to choose installation path (or select default path) so that it can copy all the above directories and files onto the specified path
4. Convert python file i.e. app.py, encrypt_data.py, decrypt_data.py to .pyc or any other format so that user cannot read it
5. (Optional) Finally creates shortcut on desktop so that running it can execute app.py

I have looked into `pyinstaller` python library which converts any `app.py` to `app.exe` but it do not packs all the project files & dir into one exe.

Is there any way I can pack complete project into one bundle file which then user can use to install everything and run the application. Please suggest some good options to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller will do this for you, if you configure the spec file correctly, see [The manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

There is also [Py2Exe](https://www.py2exe.org/), but do read the manual please.